# Rails Transaction error when placing order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to place an order with braintree payment gem and everything is working fine execept one little thing 
i get this error while placing the order

```
undefined method `total_price' for nil:NilClass
```

in the order_transaction.rb file which is located in app/views/services/
this is the file

```
class OrderTransaction
    attr_reader :order,:nonce
    def initialize order, nonce
        @order=order
        @nonce=nonce
    end

    def execute
        @result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
            amount: @order.total_price,
            payment_method_nonce: @nonce)
    end

    def ok?
        @result.success?
    end
end
```

and this is the method in orders_controller.rb which is creating the transaction

```
   def charge_user
        transaction=OrderTransaction.new @order,params[:payment_method_nonce]
        transaction.execute
        transaction.ok?
    end
```

i dont get whats happening i have the method total_price in order model which is this

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
   has_many :order_items

    def total_price
        order_items.inject(0){|sum, item| sum +item.total_price }
    end
end
```

i have also used attr_reader to read the order and the nonce in order_transaction.rb file so why is it showing undefined method for nil class i'm really confused can someone help me out

this is the orders controller in controller folder

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :initialize_cart
    def create
        @order_form=OrderForm.new(user: User.new(order_params[:user]),cart: @cart)
        if @order_form.save
            notify_user
                if charge_user
            redirect_to products_path,notice:"Thank You for placing the order sir."
                end
        else
        render "carts/checkout",notice:"Something went wrong please try again."
        end
    end

    def custom
       @order_form=OrderForm.new(user: current_user,cart: @cart) 
          if @order_form.save
              notify_user
              if charge_user
            redirect_to products_path,notice:"Thank You for placing the order sir."
              end
        else
        render "carts/checkout",notice:"Something went wrong please try again sir."
        end
    end

   private

    def notify_user
      OrderMailer.order_confirmation(@order_form.order).deliver  
    end

    def order_params
        params.require(:order_form).permit(
            user:[:name,:phone,:address,:city,:country,:postal_code,:email])
    end

    def charge_user
        transaction=OrderTransaction.new @order,params[:payment_method_nonce]
        transaction.execute
        transaction.ok?
    end
end
```

Comment: Where in your `orders_controller` do you actually assign a value to `@order`? It looks like it is not set at all.

Comment: updated the question with the orders_controller.rb

Comment: Never mind i worked it out thanks anyway